# In R with the package data.table, how can one make R display the data tables fully?

Tags: r, data.table

In R, `data.table` is very useful. However, I have been having trouble with expanding data tables in that every time you list a `data.table`, it has ellipses so as to save space.

For example:

```
library(data.table)
# Generate random data table that is large
a <- data.table(a = 1:5000, b=letters[1:5])
tail(a, 150)
>         a b
1: 4851 a
2: 4852 b
3: 4853 c
4: 4854 d
5: 4855 e
---       
146: 4996 a
147: 4997 b 
148: 4998 c
149: 4999 d
150: 5000 e
```

How can I make it show everything in between?

Comment: I think this is `data.table:::print.data.table`, try `print(tail(a, 150), 150)`

Comment: you could do `data.frame(a)`. But why would you want to print `5000` entries to console???

Comment: Call the `print.data.frame(a)` method to do it without conversion of the `a` `data.table`.

Comment: OP seems to want the last 150 observations, guise

Comment: I like to use `a[1:150]`

Comment: my mistake...I usually use syntax like this to get a full print-out. e.g. `a[(nrow(a)-50):nrow(a)]` But your way is much better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This behavior is set in the `datatable.print.nrows` option.

```
getOption("datatable.print.nrows")
# [1] 100
```

You can either override this entirely, like this:

```
DTNR <- getOption("datatable.print.nrows")  ## To reset later

options(datatable.print.nrows=Inf)
tail(a, 150) ## Should give you all rows

options(datatable.print.nrows=DTNR)
tail(a, 150) ## Back to the default
```

Or you can use @rawr's suggestion and just add the parameter to `print`.

```
print(tail(a, 150), nrows = Inf)
```

Comment: +1 Just to add that calling `print(DT)` is faster than `DT` alone, since R appears to copy the `DT` when _auto-printing_ i.e. typing `DT` on its own. There was a fix in R v3.1.1 for that but testing it just now seems it still copies. Will have to look into that again: [#549](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/549).  If what's being printing though is `tail(a,150)` then the speed difference between `> tail(a,150)` and `> print(tail(a,150))` will be negligible since 150 rows is very small. Mainly affects `> DT` when `DT` is large.